# how to modify a generalized time attribute with ldap3

Tags: python-3.x, ldap3

how can I modify a generalized time attribute via modify_replace with ldap3?

if I try:

```
reset_time = datetime.datetime(1970,1,1, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
c.modify(dn, {'myGeneralizedTimeAttribute': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, [reset_time])]})
```

I get the following python error: `TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object is not iterable`

then I try: `c.modify(dn, {'myGeneralizedTimeAttribute': [(MODIFY_REPLACE, [(reset_time,)])]})` and get `TypeError: 'datetime.datetime' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

after that I convert datetime to timestamp and get ldap error:

`{'result': 19, 'dn': '', 'type': 'modifyResponse', 'message': 'NDS error: syntax violation (-613)', 'description': 'constraintViolation', 'referrals': None}`

I think the solution is very simple, but I don't see it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the problem by replacing **reset_time** with a string:

`reset_time = '19700101010000Z'`